# Using state boundary to complete polygon in QGIS

Tags: qgis

I'm creating polygons in QGIS using lat/long pairs. These polygons are regions within the state of NY. For each polygon, I know all of the interior points (within the state of NY) and all of the points on the state boundary.

How in QGIS do I use the physical state boundary to complete each polygon (sort of like a convex hull using the state boundary)?

Comment: You can use the tracing feature while digitizing a new polygon to easily trace an existing feature. Or you could digitize your polygons so they extend outside the state, and use the state polygon to clip them.